# Redis inconsistency between bigkeys and llen

Tags: redis, celery

When I scan entire redis instance using `redis-cli --bigkeys` following shortened result is returned

```
-------- summary -------

Sampled 241145 keys in the keyspace!
Total key length in bytes is 13013217 (avg len 53.96)

Biggest string found 'celery-task-meta-52b14b66-b924-4c40-b7dc-7d5b9b633470' has 6510 bytes
**Biggest   list found 'celery9' has 156519 items**
Biggest    set found '_kombu.binding.celeryev' has 52 members
Biggest   hash found 'unacked' has 544 fields
Biggest   zset found 'unacked_index' has 550 members
```

As you can see my biggest list is `celery9` with length `156519`. I am using only one keyspace

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info keyspace
# Keyspace
db0:keys=256672,expires=256659,avg_ttl=1701804
```

But when I connect to redis instance using redis-cli or even with redis connector from python and run following commands

```
127.0.0.1:6379> get celery9
(nil)
127.0.0.1:6379> llen celery9
(integer) 0
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

`nil` or zero is returned as if there was no key `celery9`.

So the question is, how to get correct length of this key? All others keys are working perfectly

Comment: The key might been deleted before you send the get/llen command.

Comment: No, thats not the case, key exists all the time